# Why Some Variables are Declared with an * Asterisk in Objective-C

Tags: ios, c, objective-c

I am just starting to learn Objective-C. I am confused to see that some types of variables are sometimes declared with an * asterisk, others are not. For example these are delcared with a `*`:

```objectivec
@property NSString *firstName;
NSString * mainString = @"Hello World!";
NSNumber *longNumber = @42l;
NSArray *unsortedStrings = @[@"gammaString", @"alphaString", @"betaString"];
```

And these are not:

```objectivec
int someInteger = 42;
NSInteger anInteger = 64;
id firstObject = @"someString";
NSRange substringRange = [mainString rangeOfString:@"long"];
```

I found this explanation from Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW1

> Both these properties are for Objective-C objects, so they use an asterisk to indicate that they are C pointers.

But this explanation is too general and vague for me to understand the concept. I know `type *` means it is a pointer type, and this type stores pointers of that type. But why some types are declared with `*`, others are not?

Comment: Note that "*" is from the C language, not Objective-C. It means "pointer to", as Rob explains in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `int` type is not object. It is a C language “primitive data type”. You generally interact with primitive C data types directly. E.g.,

```objectivec
int i = 0;   // it’s now `0`
i = 42;      // it’s now `42`
```

The `NSInteger` is just an alias for another primitive data type, `long`. The `NSRange` is a struct (thus, also not an object), so the same rule applies. So, for basic interaction with these primitive data types, no `*` pointer reference is generally needed. (There actually are times you also deal with pointers to primitive data types, but that is beyond the scope of this question.)

But `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and `NSArray`, however, *are* objects, so you must use pointers when declaring them.

---

Note, you've included `id` in the latter list where `*` is not used:

```objectivec
id firstObject = @"foo";
```

Be very careful. This actually is a bit misleading, because `firstObject` actually *is* a pointer to the `@"someString"`, a `NSString` object. The `id` is an exception to the way we generally declare pointers with `*` and is discussed in [Objective-C is a Dynamic Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW18)), “The `id` type defines a generic object pointer.”

It’s analogous to declaring a `NSString` pointer, but “you lose compile-time information about the object”. Compare the `id` pointer to the `NSString *` to the following syntax:

```objectivec
NSString *secondObject = @"bar";
```

This latter `secondObject` is `NSString *` pointer, but because we explicitly declared it as a `NSString *` pointer, the compiler knows that you are dealing with a string (thus the compiler can perform greater validation regarding your subsequent use of that pointer). With `id`, you do not enjoy this compile-time validation.

For example, here are two invalid attempts to call `removeObject` method on two `NSString` objects. `NSString` has no such method. The `NSString *` reference provides useful compile-time error message that `id` does not afford us:

[image]

Now, if you used the `id` type and tried to run that code, it would crash when it attempted to call `removeObject` on `firstObject`. But, where possible, it is much better to have the compiler tell us about the error during compile-time, rather than at run-time.

So the `id` pattern should be used sparingly, only when you really need Objective-C’s dynamic type behaviors.